# Flex-grow does not work for column direction

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn the flexbox layout. I saw a tutorial speaks about flex-grow and flex-shrink classes and all provided examples in this course works fine with flex-direction: row.

I tried to apply them with `flex-direction: column`, but it does not work as I wanted. I googled it, but I didn't find a suitable answer to grow a flex item when the direction is set it up as a column.

My code is below. Could anyone fix my CSS to get flex-grow/shrink work in column direction please?

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    border:solid 4px #000;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;

}

.flex-item {
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #A62E5C;
    flex-grow: 3;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #9BC850;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #675BA7;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #620542;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item">Flex 1</div>
            <div class="flex-item">Flex 2</div>
            <div class="flex-item">Flex 3</div>
            <div class="flex-item">Flex 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: In case you are confused about the duplicate, the issue is you need to set an explicit height on the flex container. 100% is a relative height that inherits from its ancestor. You have no explicit height set for any of the ancestors, so it doesn't know how much to grow.

Comment: Yep, I tried that after I posted my question and it works, sorry it was a dump question thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works but you won't see anything different because `flex-grow` will consider the **free space** to make the element growing and by default there is no free space in a column direction since the height is defined by content unlike when using a row direction where the width is usually 100% and we have free space.

Also, in your case you used `height:100%` and since there is no height defined on the parent element it will fallback to `auto` thus it will be the height of the content and the logic above will apply.

Use a fixed height and you will see the effect:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 4px #000;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #A62E5C;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #9BC850;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #675BA7;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #620542;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 3</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

And in order to fix the `height:100%` you need to add it to parent elements:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 4px #000;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #A62E5C;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #9BC850;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #675BA7;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #620542;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 3</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Flex 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

---

> The flex-grow CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex
>   item. It specifies **how much of the available space** in the flex
>   container **should be assigned to that item**.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)</sup>